# Selecting a radio button does not trigger @input

Tags: vue.js

I having a problem with a radio-group in a child component of a larger form, all presented through the Vuetify framework.

I cannot get the radio-group to trigger an @input event whenever any of its options are selected.  The selected radio value is emitted when I change the value in the `Results` text area.

The problem remains if I abandon the Vuelidate involvement and set the model in the radio group to `v-model="form.sourceid"`.

My code is:

```
<template>
    <form @input="submit" class="form">
      <v-card-text>
        <v-radio-group
            label="Risk type"
            :mandatory="false"
            v-model="$v.form.sourceid.$model"
        >
          <v-radio
              v-for="risk in risks"
              :key="risk.value"
              :label="risk.label"
              :value="risk.riskId"
              :checked="risk.riskId == form.sourceid"
              color="teal"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
        <v-text-field
            v-model.trim="form.results"
            type="text"
            label="Results"
            box
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card-text>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
  import {required} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

  const FORM_TEMPLATE = {
    sourceid: null,
    results: null,
  }
  export default {
    props: {
      wizardData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        form: {...FORM_TEMPLATE, ...this.wizardData},
        risks: [
          { label: 'Soil',riskId: '1'},
          { label: 'Water',riskId: '2'},
          { label: 'Agrichemicals',riskId: '3'},
        ]
      }
    },
    validations: {
      form: {
        sourceid: {
          required
        },

      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit () {
        this.$emit('update',
          { data: this.form,
            valid: !this.$v.$invalid
          }
        )
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

The contents of `wizardData` when using a 'clean form' are:

```
{
"sourceid": null,
"results": null
}
```

My `submit` method is:

```
submit () {
        this.$emit('update',
          { data: this.form,
            valid: !this.$v.$invalid  //this line removed if testing without Vuelidate
          }
        )
      },
```

Any assistance muchly appreciated.
Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to read the docs with both eyes open and discover that radio buttons respond to the `change` event.

So, altering the v-radio-group attributes to read the following solved my problem:

```
<v-radio-group
      label="Risk type"
      v-model="$v.form.sourceid.$model"
      :mandatory="false"
      @change="submit"
>
```

Cheers, Tom